# putting menu in header

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 178px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#left, #center, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}

#center {
    width: 1100px;
}

#left {
    background: url(left.gif) repeat-x;
}

#center {
    background: url(center.gif) no-repeat center center;
}

#right {
    background: url(right.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

See: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GE3x/15/)

I want to put a horizontal menu in orange part of center section and another horizontal menu in yellow part;

I tried this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center">

        <ul id="menu1">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Partnerships</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

         <ul id="menu2">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Partnerships</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Added CSS:

```
#menu1 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
#menu1 li {float:right; margin-left:5px;}
#menu1 a {color:violet;}

#menu2 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
#menu2 li {float:right; margin-left:5px;}
#menu2 a {color:#000;}
```

See: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GE3x/27/)

But no had no success, please help!

Comment: hi, I can't access the link

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up the edit to get the links working.  thankfully +Theraot fixed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative positioning (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning) e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/67UWv/

**css**

```
#menu1 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:85px;
    right:30px;
}

#menu2 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:110px;
    right:30px;
}
```

**edit** - related to last comments

in order to remove the white spacing around the menu image it is required to set `margin:0` for the `body` element to override the default user agent style rules.

```
body{
margin:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67UWv/1/

**edit** - response to the latest comments

The white gap noticed was caused in ff from the beginning (test original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6GE3x/27/show/ ) when content was placed within `#center` div. So there is some issue there when using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` and also adding content.

In order to avoid using an actual table for layout and all the consequences related to them, it is possible to position the center part using absolute layout as follows,

### http://jsfiddle.net/eH2m6/show/

http://jsfiddle.net/eH2m6/

**css**

```
div {
    height: 178px;
}

#wrapper {
    /* display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; */
    width: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
    /* display: table-cell; */
/*the following will make #left and #right take full width*/
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

#center {
    width: 1100px;
/*the following will position #center in the center*/
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-550px;
}

#left {
    background: url(http://dentaliran.ir/left.gif) repeat-x;
}

#center {
    background: url(http://dentaliran.ir/center.gif) no-repeat center center;
   
}

#right {
    background: url(http://dentaliran.ir/right.gif) repeat-x;
}

#menu1 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:85px;
    right:30px;
}
#menu1 li {float:right; margin-left:5px;}
#menu1 a {color:violet;}

#menu2 {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:110px;
    right:30px;
}
#menu2 li {float:right; margin-left:5px;}
#menu2 a {color:#000;}

body{
margin:0px;
}
```

*has been tested in ie8,ie9,chrome32.x,ff25.x*

Comment: no, please zoom in browser you can see, there is a white gap between center part and top of browser, that's my problem.

Comment: @user3250818 zooming in/out a browser is not a behaviour you should be taking into consideration. It depends on each browser and it is unpredictable.

Comment: @user3250818 i see what you mean just add `body{margin:0px}` and it will be fine. Basically these are the browser's/user agent default css style rules.

Comment: melc's answer worked in chrome and IE but in firefox as i said there was a gap between center img and top of browser, I used table instead of div to sort it out. thanks

Comment: @user3250818 the answer provided is not related to this issue, it seems this is something that occurred from the beginning. I just edited the answer proposing an alternative solution.